# parameters of broadphase collision detection in bullet library

Tags: bulletphysics

I am trying to learn about bullet library and collision detection in it.I got the basic theory and concept of broadphase collision detection. However it's hard to know how it is implemented and what are the parameters of broadphase and narrowphase collision detection in bullet library??? Is there any resource on bullet apart from that manual??

Answer (score 1):

Well there's the source code:

https://code.google.com/p/bullet/

And all the documentation on each class:

http://bulletphysics.org/Bullet/BulletFull/annotated.html

As well as the wiki:
http://www.bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php?title=Broadphase